# Display the content of an array in a new browser tab

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I've made this script that generates an array containing lines in CSV format.

```
<?php
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out,$tabcsv,"\n\r");
fclose($out);
?>
```

I would like the content of this array to be sent to a new browser page thanks to a button, but I don't want a CSV file to be generated.

The problem is that this script sends the content to the current browser page and that this content can't be formated.

Edit :

```
<?php
$out = fopen('output', 'w');
fputcsv($out,$tabcsv,"\n\r");
fclose($out);
?>

<form action="output" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" value="Export CSV" />
</form>
```

This new script is a bit closer to my goal (new tab, formatable content). But it generates a file on the server and I really want to avoid that.

Comment: you can open a popup with javascript. Php doesn't open the popup.

Comment: you cannot create a new tab on-demand. there's only "window.open()", which MAY get translated into a new tab instead, depending on the user's browser settings.

Comment: ...or make the button a link and give it the target="_blank" attribute.

Comment: My problem is how to send the content of the array to a page... With the first script, the content is displayed on the current page. I've made an update in my question. Now, the content is sent to a new page. But the code seems quite dirty to me and it generates a file... I think there is something to do with header and svg, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: if you want to do that with php just do a header('Content-type: image/svg+xml') then followed by the xml file that creates the svg graphics
echo '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg widt
</svg>';